# Is there any way to integrate Databricks and sonarlint for pyspark/python code? If not, then what can be the alternatives?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, sonarlint

I want  my databricks notebook to automatically analyze the errors, bugs, suggestions etc, to make my work more efficient.
I came to know about sonar lint but can't find it's implementation with databricks. Pls, suggest some alternative, if any.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting out of the Databricks web interface and use VSCode with Sonarlint thanks to this VSCode Extension : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=paiqo.databricks-vscode

It will allow you to execute your code on the Databricks cluster from within VSCode notebooks and use any linting / formatting library you are used to use.